# pinescript boolean variable has an integer value

Tags: python, pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, boolean-expression

I've got this pinescript code I'm trying to translate to python but for some reason the boolean variable has an integer value? or an integer -like syntax? would appericate any form of help

code:

```
a = abs(high - low)
b = abs(close - open)
c = 0.45

rv = b < c*a
sl = rv == 1 and high > y and close < y and open < y
```

for some more context here the entire script is on tradingview,
it the "Rob Hoffman's Inventory retracement bar" by ucsgears.

Comment: Does your code exhibit some unwanted behaviour? Can you provide some sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: Which variable are you talking about and why are you thinking that it has an integer value?

Comment: @vitruvius rv is the one I'm talking about

Comment: @quamrana I don't have any output as I'm trying to understand the code

Comment: I think in pine v1 1/0 was synonymous with true/false. In py you can treat `rv` as a boolean and substitute `rv == 1` with `rv == true`